# maven multi-module project with one plugin module

Tags: maven, multi-module

I am thinking about creating a multi-module project in maven, with one plugin module (i.e. this module is used as a plugin in other projects, not a dependency).

**Question**: Is it feasible to have a plugin as a module in a multi module maven project?

Comment: Yeah sure, this is feasible. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions. An excessive number of poorly received questions that are off-topic will get you banned from asking questions, and you do not want that do you?

Answer (score 2):

It is feasible and it is also documented on the [official maven multi-module/reactor page](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) concerning how having a plugin as module is handled by the build (bold is mine):

> Because modules within a multi-module build can depend on each other, it is important that The reactor sorts all the projects in a way that guarantees any project is built before it is required.
>
> The following relationships are honoured when sorting projects:
>
> - a project dependency on another module in the build
> - **a plugin declaration where the plugin is another modules in the build**
> - **a plugin dependency on another module in the build**
>     [..]

Once the plugin is installed and deployed, it will then not bring with it any knowledge of its *module nature*, that is, it will be seen as a normal plugin by the projects that will use it via its unique maven coordinates (GAV).
The same is applied to archetypes, which can be modules of a multi module project and then be used individually.

Also note that you can have - as an example - an [aggregator project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Aggregation) of projects (then modules) completely unrelated between each other, and, say, just aggregate then because you want to build them all together (often not really meaningful, but useful in some cases).