# In a multi-module project can Gradle build a plugin as one module and then use that plugin in the same build?

Tags: gradle, plugins, multi-module

We have a Gradle project with a bunch of modules. One of those modules is a custom code generator, written as a Gradle plugin. We want to run that code-generator plugin in another module later in the same overall multi-module build, in order to test the code generator.

We know how to create a separate project on the fly and run the code generator in that, but we need to run the code generator in the main project, not in a temporary test project.

Nothing we have tried works, and the Gradle documentation doesn't appear to address this. It seems to be fundamental to Gradle's design, because the entire set of plugins used in a build is basically a single program, assembled at the start. Trying to add a just-now-built plugin after the fact seems unsupported, or we're missing something.

The best we've been able to come up with so far is to implement the plugin in Java (Kotlin would also have worked), so the Gradle plugin is just a thin Gradle skin over the implementation, and call the Java implementation directly when running the code generator in the other module. This works, but it means we aren't actually testing the Gradle portion of the code generator.

This is natively supported in Maven ([maven multi-module project with one plugin module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949181/maven-multi-module-project-with-one-plugin-module), and https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html), which is not surprising because every plugin in Maven runs in a separate class loader. If it's not possible in Gradle, that would be one of the few cases where Gradle doesn't have feature parity.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky way to do this is to run the newly-compiled plugin via Gradle's test kit runner.

A cleaner way to do this is to write plugins as thin shells of code written to Gradle's API that delegate the real work to plain old Java (or Kotlin) utility methods. This has a number of advantages:

1. You can unit test the utility methods.
2. You can use the utility methods for other purposes unrelated to the plugin.
3. You can call the utility methods directly from other modules in the project, thereby accomplishing what the plugin would have done if you could have built it and then called it in the same build.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the above answer.

Instead of calling the plugin like a plugin, add a main method that accepts the same parameters that Gradle plugin configuration passed to the plugin.

Then call the plugin's main using Gradle's Java exec task:

```
task(generateFoo, type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.bar.Foo'
    classpath = configurations.runtimeClasspath
    args = ["arg1", "${projectDir}/src/generated/java"]
}
```

Note the args: those are the same pieces of information that used to be passed in via Gradle configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'foo-plugin'
generateFoo {
    theArg "arg1"
    outputDir "${projectDir}/src/generated/java"
}
```

Because the runtime classpath used by Java exec is the one for the calling module, you may encounter runtime classloader problems.

If that happens, it's easily fixed. Just change the rewritten plugin to a fat jar:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Foo Fat JAR', 'Main-Class': 'com.bar.Foo'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-exec'
    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
artifacts {
    archives fatJar
}
```

And then execute the fat jar with Java exec:

```
  def fooGenerate = task(generateFoo, type: JavaExec) {
      main = 'com.bar.Foo'
      classpath = files("${projectDir}/../foo-plugin-module/build/libs/foo-plugin-module-exec.jar")
      args = ["arg1", "${projectDir}/src/generated/java"]
  }
```

Finally, make the dependent module's compile task depend on the code generation:

```
compileJava.mustRunAfter fooGenerate
```

If you use the fatJar approach, you don't even need to declare implementation project(":foo") in the dependent modules.

It might be also be possible to use Gradle's composite builds for this (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html).